# Arbitrary vlan interface name - undocumented configuration?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, vlan, alpine

Today i was playing around with ethernet adapters and vlans in Alpine Linux. I tried to give the interfaces arbitrary names.

After looking at the source i had the following example working

Ethernet adapter named `lan01` configured as `DHCP client` and a VLAN on this adapter named lan-test on VLAN ID 100

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto lan01
iface lan01 inet dhcp
        hostname alpine

auto lan-test
iface lan-test inet static
        vlan-id 100
        vlan-raw-device lan01
        address 10.10.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

ifup and ifdown in Alpine Linux uses busybox.

Nowhere in any documentation i found the option `vlan-id`. However the `vlan-raw-device` is found in most documentation/man pages.
So this brings me to the question: Why is this option not documented anywhere?

Some of my guesses:

- It is old and deprecated thus should not be used anymore
- It is new and untested.
- It never got documented properly
- I just overlooked it many many times in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Quick dig do you have a Mellanox card ?

https://github.com/alpinelinux/linux-stable-grsec/blob/d9a468ffb147fe3a5ebd305ff1e1bdb7fe3ac452/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/mcg.c#L923

Comment: My Alpine is running as a VM on VMware Player.